# How do I compare if *ALL* strings of a NSArray are equal ?

Tags: objective-c

How do I compare if **all** strings of a NSArray are equal ?

Should I scan the array for each string ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSArray` class is general-purpose so it won't contain functionality to perform this, so yes, you'll have to check each string yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this by creating a new set from the array. The set will only contain unique entries so if the number of elements in the set is 1 then all items in the array was equal.

```
NSSet *uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:yourArray];
if ([uniqueItems count] < 2) {
    // All items in "yourArray" are the same (no matter how many they are)
}
```

In the above example I'm considering an empty set (meaning an empty array) as a being unique as well. If you don't then you can change the if-statement to `if ([uniqueItems count] == 1) { ... }`

---

This will also work for any object, not just strings.

Comment: Interesting. Not much code this way, and probably quick for a small array or when there are few unique elements. However, in the case of a large array or many unique elements, this requires a lot of extra comparisons.

Comment: @noa I assumed that, since the OP felt that all elements could be equal, it would very likely only be a few unique values and probably not more than a few hundred values total in the array in which case performance shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

trojanfoe is right. You can enhance NSArray with category and do something like this ...

```
  NSArray *array = @[ @"A", @"B", @"C" ];

  __block BOOL allObjectsAreEqual = YES;
  if ( array.count > 1 ) {
    NSString *firstObject = array[0];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^void(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      if ( idx == 0 ) {
        return;
      }

      if ( ( allObjectsAreEqual = [firstObject isEqualToString:obj] ) == NO ) {
        *stop = YES;
      }
    }];

  // And here check for allObjectsAreEqual ...
```

... there're many ways how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to check whether **all the strings are equal to each other**?

```
@interface NSArray (MyAdditions)

- (BOOL) isFilledWithEqualObjects {
    if (!self.count) return YES;
    id firstObject = [self objectAtIndex:0];
    for (id obj in self) {
        // Avoid comparing firstObject to itself (and any other pointers to
        // firstObject)
        if (firstObject == obj) continue;
        if (![firstObject isEqual:obj]) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

That example uses `-isEqual:`, to work with any kind of object. If you know the contents are strings, you can use `-isEqualToString:` instead:

```
        if (![firstObject isEqualToString:obj]) return NO;
```

Comment: "==" is wrong for comparing strings. Should be "isEqualToString"

Comment: The == check is to avoid comparing `firstObject` to itself. The line that does the comparisons is the one below that, which uses `-isEqual:`.